# How to get the reference of child controllers from parentController in Ember JS?

Tags: javascript, validation, ember.js

I have a Question model object that has answers array. Both Question and Answer have some properties to be validated. I am using ember-validations. When user is trying to save, I need to trigger validations on question and answers. So, I am triggering the Question controller validations but how do I force the QuestionController to wait for AnswerControllers to validate? Since AnswerControllers have reference to the QuestionController (parent), they can observe a property on the parent and trigger their validations. But the problem is how do I force QuestionController to wait for the answer controller validations? Question has its own properties and hence, QuestionController cannot be an arraycontroller!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that your child controllers are related to some array controller using itemController.  Using the context of the array controller, you can iterate it, and you will have each instance of the child controller.

```
App.FooController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'bar',
  doSomething: function(){
    this.forEach(function(itemController){
      console.log(itemController);
    });
  }
});
```

But as you've mentioned, your questions isn't an Array controller, so I'm left guessing that you are probably showing the answers using itemController in the template

```
{{#each foo in answers itemController='answer'}}

{{/each}}
```

This presents a problem, since you have no access to the controllers.  But you can overcome this with `render`

So instead of doing the above each, you do

```
{{render 'answers' answers}}
```

and you have an answers template, and an answers controller.

#### Template

```
{{#each foo in answers}}

{{/each}}
```

#### Controller

```
App.AnswersController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'bar',
  doSomething: function(){
    this.forEach(function(itemController){
      console.log(itemController);
    });
  }
});
```

And now you can iterate your children.